# Javascript to check a unique checkbox on form selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, selection

I am a front-end designer and developer with limited JS and jQuery experience. I always know I could learn more, but time has never allowed for that (I could also be using this as an excuse. ; ) Nonetheless, I have an issue on a website I'm currently developing that I need some JS/jQuery help on.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63777185/screenshot.png

This image represents subproducts on a product page. When a user opens the selection box and selects an option, it doesn't automatically check the checkbox. I was able to find something here on StackOverflow that worked with minor tweaks, but the problem comes when there is more than one product. The script that I was using selected all the checkboxes instead of the unique one that I needed.

Another problem is that this code is dynamically generated, so I don't control the output. So, I thought the best way to tackle this was to do addClass to the elements I needed, with an integer to make it unique (since they need to be unique). From there, I didn't know how to get the two pieces of code to work together. This is horribly wrong and you're free to laugh, but this is what I have:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select').each(function(i,j) {
            $(this).addClass('selection'+i);
        });
        $('input').each(function(i,j) {
            $(this).addClass('check'+i);
    });
    $('.selection'+i).change(function() {
        var selected = $('select option:selected');
        if (selected.val() == "null") {
            $('.check'+i).prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.check'+i).prop('checked', true);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! : )

Comment: Your solution will probably work, but it looks like you should be able to use jQuery traversal methods instead: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/

Comment: If they're unique, you should be using IDs rather than classes. But it's better to use the traversal methods, as Jason P said. Without seeing your HTML, we can't provide an answer that shows the precise methods to use.

Comment: Here is the HTML: http://trademo.traditionsjewishgifts.com/GRWM1.html